# how to paste string to React Admin <DateInput>

Tags: react-admin

"react-admin": "^4.3.1",
How to setup DateInput in React Admin so that you copy and paste string to input?
I have DateInput like this

```
<DateInput source="to" label="End Date"  />
```

and paste doesn't work on it.

Answer (score 1):

`<DateInput>` uses a native date input. Your browser doesn't allow pasting arbitrary strings in an `<input type="date">`, so react-admin doesn't allow it either.

If you want to allow any date format, change to a `<TextInput>` and parse it to a Date manually using the `parse` prop.